# Копирование строк из csv в csv C#

Tags: c#, csv

Есть csv файл. В нем строки в формате 1234,123456 - это правильный формат строки. Но в нем попадаются неправильные строки, например 123,123456 или 1234,1234. А так же иногда попадаются строки такие 01ОД,123456 или 012№6,123456.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы из данного csv взять строки правильного формата, создать новый csv только с правильным содержимым. С первыми двумя вариантами справиться легко, достаточно сделать условие if(str.IndexOf("," ==4 && str.Lenght==11) - то эти варианты не попадают. Как сделать так, чтобы попадали строки в которых нет букв и символов, кроме ","?

Comment: Это одноразовая задача? Так-то можно формулами в Excel скрыть все кривые форматы и скопировать нужное.

Comment: Судя по другому вашему вопросу, размер файла 1,5 Гб, 120 млн. строк? Регулярки или string.Split+int.Parse будут создавать кучу мусора. Если нужна высокая производительность, нужно вручную разбирать поток байтов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, как раз тот вопрос. А можете подсказать как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Медленный, но короткий способ

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\d{4},\d{6}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
bool IsStringValidRegex(string str)
{
    return rx.IsMatch(str);
}
```

Быстрый, но длинный

```
bool IsStringValid(string str)
{
    int index = 0;
    int digitsBefore = 0;
    int digitsAfter = 0;

    while (str.Length > index && char.IsDigit(str[index]))
    {
        digitsBefore++;
        index ++;
    }   

    if (str.Length <= index || str[index]!=',') return false;
    index++;

    while (str.Length > index && char.IsDigit(str[index]))
    {
        digitsAfter++;
        index++;
    }
    return digitsBefore == 4 && digitsAfter == 6 && index == str.Length;
}
```

Как использовать

```
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValid("1234,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValid("123,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValid("1234,1234"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValid("01ОД,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValid("012№6,123456"));

Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

Console.WriteLine(IsStringValidRegex("1234,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValidRegex("123,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValidRegex("1234,1234"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValidRegex("01ОД,123456"));
Console.WriteLine(IsStringValidRegex("012№6,123456"));
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
False
False
False
-------------------------- -
True
False
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, воспользоваться регулярным выражением: `\d{4},\d{6}` и натравить `RegEx.IsMatch`